# Proving differential equation has no bounded solutions

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

How do I prove that the $2^{nd}$ order ODE

$$\ddot{x}(t) - \sin(x(t)) = \sin(t)$$

has no solutions $~\{x(0),\dot{x}(0)\} \in \mathbb{R}^2~$ for which $|x(t)| < \frac{\pi}{2} \quad \forall \ t\in[0,\infty]~$?

Comment: Physically, this is an inverted pendulum, that is, angle $x=0$ is the upright position, with periodic forcing. Formulated this way, it is intuitive that this will fall down and might end up in oscillations around the lower stable equilibrium point at $x=\pm\pi$ or in a continued rotation. The forcing is large enough that random resonance will give a quasi-chaotic behavior. Anyway, it seems extremely unlikely that the region $|x|<\pi/2$ will be never left, that the uncontrolled forcing will keep the pendulum about upright.

Comment: Correct, this is a simplified version of a system similar to an inverted pendulum. However, in the full system this result is less intuitive, so it would be best if I could find a proof that this is the case, rather than relying on similarity to the more intuitive simplified problem.